# Firebase Dynamic Links <subdomain>.page.link does not launch app

Tags: firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

Am building my second app and like the first I've added the dynamic link feature.
The new link looks like `https://<subdomain>.page.link/gr123` does not trigger app when clicked just goes direct to browser - playstore.

Here the code that can't seem to open app when installed:

```
 private void sendToInviteScreen() {

        String link = "https://etablebanking.page.link/gr/?invitedto=" + userInviteID;

        Intent intent = new AppInviteInvitation.IntentBuilder(getString(R.string.invitation_title))
                .setMessage("Welcome to etable bank ")
                .setDeepLink(Uri.parse(link))
                .setCustomImage(Uri.parse(getString(R.string.invitation_custom_image)))
                .setCallToActionText(getString(R.string.invitation_cta))
                .build();
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_INVITE);

    }
```

What the previous app uses and works perfectly:
The old link looks like `https://<subdomain>.app.goo.gl/?link=`

```
 private void sendToInviteScreen() {

        String link = "https://f8msr.app.goo.gl/?invitedto=" + userInviteID;

        Intent intent = new AppInviteInvitation.IntentBuilder(getString(R.string.invitation_title))
                .setMessage("Manage and control all calls")
                .setDeepLink(Uri.parse(link))
                .setCustomImage(Uri.parse(getString(R.string.invitation_custom_image)))
                .setCallToActionText(getString(R.string.invitation_cta))
                .build();
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_INVITE);

    }
```

Comment: Can you paste in your app manifest? You should have an intent filter in there added for the page.link domain

Comment: added a intent filter for both dynamic link and shortened link and it now displays as one of the apps that can open the link.